# MVC2 Futures conflicting with existing System.Web.Mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, asp.net-mvc-futures

I downloaded MVC2 Futures and referenced it to my current MVC2 Project. However, if I want to call an HtmlHelper from MVC2 Futures I need to `<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc" %>`

So I decided to add it on my Web.Config:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="Xpedite.Mvc.Html" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

but, this caused me errors. Could this assemblies co-exist? If yes, How?

Comment: Why are you using MVC2 futures when MVC3 has already been released?

Comment: @KirkWoll Maybe it's because he's not targetting MVC3? .NET 3.5 comes to mind.

Comment: Are you certain you're targeting the correct version of MVC (2) in your project reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need the MVC3 Futures pack:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/54306

The MVC2 Future was made to work against MVC1. I had the same issue and upgrading to the next futures release solved it for me.

Comment: I had resolved it by rebuilding and cleaning the solution, thanks for the advice though.